# manually update django model instance in put request. django django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, put, insert-update

The way I am doing my put request by exposing the parent model and then searching through the room_set becasue I need to see if the user has permissions to mess with the parent models related objects.

now with that away, I am trying to do a manual put.

This put will act more like a patch but the CORS policy doesn't like it when I use PATCH in my local. so I put.

So Im a little confused about what to do next. How do I add the new value to my object or ignore the attribute on my model if I don't have any data on it in the request?

Here is the model and the put request.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    privateroom = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    semiprivateroom = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seatedcapacity = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    standingcapacity = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    minimumspend = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    surroundsoundamenity = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    outdoorseatingamenity = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stageamenity = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    televisionamenity = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    screenprojectoramenity = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    naturallightamenity = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    wifiamenity = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    wheelchairaccessibleamenity = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cocktailseatingseatingoption = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    classroomseatingoption = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ushapeseatingoption = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sixtyroundseatingoption = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    boardroomseatingoption = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    theaterseatingoption = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hallowsquareseatingoption = models.BooleanField(default=False)




 def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        venuepk = kwargs.get('venuepk', None)
        venue = get_object_or_404(Venue, pk=venuepk)
        roompk = kwargs.get('roompk')
        venuerooms = Venue.room_set.all()
        roomobject = None
        for room in venuerooms:
            if room.pk == int(roompk):
                roomobject = Room.objects.get(pk = roompk)
                serialized = RoomSerializer(request.data)
                if serialized.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    data = serialized.validated_data
                    roomobject
```

so I printed the serialized data and I got what is below. Looks like its nothing more than a dictionary value and setting a default if a key doesn't exist.

```
RoomSerializer(data={u'minimumspend': None, u'seatedcapacity': 50, u'standingcapacity': 65, u'name': u'The Dean', u'privateroom': u'privateroom'}):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    name = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=100, required=False)
    online = BooleanField(required=False)
    description = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=1000, required=False)
    privateroom = BooleanField(required=False)
    semiprivateroom = BooleanField(required=False)
    seatedcapacity = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=10, required=False)
    standingcapacity = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, max_length=10, required=False)
    minimumspend = IntegerField(allow_null=True, max_value=32767, min_value=0, required=False)
    surroundsoundamenity = BooleanField(required=False)
    outdoorseatingamenity = BooleanField(required=False)
    stageamenity = BooleanField(required=False)
    televisionamenity = BooleanField(required=False)
    screenprojectoramenity = BooleanField(required=False)
    naturallightamenity = BooleanField(required=False)
    wifiamenity = BooleanField(required=False)
    wheelchairaccessibleamenity = BooleanField(required=False)
    cocktailseatingseatingoption = BooleanField(required=False)
    classroomseatingoption = BooleanField(required=False)
    ushapeseatingoption = BooleanField(required=False)
    sixtyroundseatingoption = BooleanField(required=False)
    boardroomseatingoption = BooleanField(required=False)
    theaterseatingoption = BooleanField(required=False)
    hallowsquareseatingoption = BooleanField(required=False)
    venue = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Venue.objects.all())
```

Comment: Can you brief what all things you need to do with `put()` in you case ?

Comment: update all of the model but only on certain requests. What is on the front end is several form instances on several different pages. They build out an object on each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead of your `put()`

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    venuepk = kwargs.get('venuepk', None)
    if not venuepk:
        return Respose("venuepk is empty")
    venue = get_object_or_404(Venue, pk=venuepk)
    room = venue.room_set.all().get(id=int(roompk))
    # lets assume that you have to update different fields on different requests
    # So make a  'dict' that has 'key' same as in your `Room` model as below
    update_dict = {
        "description":"some description",
        "online":True,
        "minimumspend":10
    }
    room.update(**update_dict)
    return Response("updated")
```

Is this what you are looking for ?